# How to get triggered button id in Drupal 8 Form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-8

Hi I would like to know a way to get the index id of the button clicked in Drupal 8 form.
I have a form withe some fields. It has Add, Remove,Add More buttons.

I want to remove the value of the particular field when I click on remove button.
In order to do so I need to know the index of the clicked button . I was able to achieve that in Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 But cant achieve that in Drupal 8.

**Drupal 6:**

```
function field_add($form, &$form_state) {

  $element_key = $form_state['clicked_button']['#parents'][1];
}
```

**Drupal 7:**

```
function field_add($form, &$form_state) {

  $element_key = $form_state['triggering_element']['#parents'][1];
}
```

How to get the same in Drupal 8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to Figure it .
Here is a way to achieve it in Drupal 8.

```
public function field_add(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element_key = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#parents'][1];
}
```

Comment: Strange, for me works: $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#parents'][0];

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8 I named my button using attribute "#name" to be able to use this code:

```
$clickedElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];
```

By this way you prevent a possible issue with the array index being different.

Comment: This is less brittle than replying on #array_parents.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 this has worked in my case

```
$clickedElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#array_parents'][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9 this worked for me

```
$form_state->getUserInput()['_triggering_element_name'];
```